# How do I apply Chrome's native loading="lazy" to all my images?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome added support for native lazy image loading in Chrome 76 which I found out from [this article](https://medium.com/bbc-design-engineering/native-lazy-loading-has-arrived-c37a165d70a5).

The premise is that you add `loading="lazy"` to all of your `img` tags.

Instead of going through and editing multiple img tags on multiple pages, how can I globally apply this setting to all images?

Comment: You cannot. If your server doesn't return an HTML page with the `loading` attribute already set for every image, and you have to add it after the page is loaded (e.g. using JS), then its utility is basically nullified.

Comment: ctrl + f "<img "

Comment: Wow! That seems like a massive miss in Chrome's implementation of this "feature"...